# CSS footer width:100% causes horizontal scroll

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble giving a footer 100% width. It causes a horizontal scroll bar to appear. When I lower the 100% it makes an orange bar at the side because that's the background. I read that having a padding on the element could cause it but I'm pretty sure there isn't any padding present on the content of my footer bar so could anyone help out?

```
/* CSS Document */

/*-- RESET | Based on Eric Meyer --*/

ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding:0px;
}

li {
    line-height:25px;   
}
/*-- BODY BORDER --*/
.bt, .br, .bb, .bl { 
    background: white; position: fixed; z-index: 99999; 
}
.bl, .br {
    top: 0; bottom: 0; width: 5px; 
}
.bt, .bb {
    left: 0; right: 0; height: 5px; 
}
.bt { 
    top: 0; 
}
.br { 
    right: 0; 
}
.bb { 
    bottom: 0; 
}
.bl { 
    left: 0;
}


/*-- MAIN --*/
html, body { 
    height: 100%; 
}
body {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: #FCD9CA; 
}

.clear { 
    clear: both; overflow: hidden; 
}

.sidebar {
    padding: 15px 0;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black; 
}

.sb-slider {

    padding-top:0px;
    margin-top:0px; 
}
.container {
    padding-bottom:100px;   
}

 
.logo {
    padding-left:15%;
    position:relative;
    top:125px;
    margin: 0 auto; 
}

.top {
    padding-left:5%;
    position:relative;
    top:200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.footercontact {
    padding: 15px 0;
}
.footer {
    padding-left:5% 
}
footer {
    
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    background:#fff;
}
```

I've made a fiddle to show you the problem
http://jsfiddle.net/9gh3ht48/2/

Comment: Try setting `margin: 0` on html/body. And for goodness' sake, set `z-index` to something meaningful, like `2`; I highly doubt you have 99,999 layers on your page.

Comment: You need `box-sizing: border-box;` probably, and if you're really just interested in it filling the viewport, you'd be better off with `width: 100vw;` instead of `100%`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As @Lal mentioned the problem is caused by the left padding on `.footer`.

I'm assuming this padding is a necessary part of your design so a better solution would be to set the `box-sizing` property of your footer to `border-box`:

```
.footer {
    padding-left:5% 
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3uye47dj/2/)

---

**Edit**

Ok try this:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9gh3ht48/4/)

```
.footer {
   padding-left:5%;
   margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this would've been a better solution, but it's not working :(

Comment: This worked for me.  I had some extra padding on the parent container that was causing the horizontal scroll.

Answer (score 10):

Just remove the 100% width from your footer and add right:0; instead.

That rule combined with left:0 will ensure the element spans the full width and any padding and borders will not cause a scroll.

(The box-sizing rule should have worked also assuming you had the vendor prefixes for older browsers and weren't supporting less than IE8)

Comment: Thank's i tried but still a scrollbar i've made a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9gh3ht48/2/

Comment: The issue has nothing to do with the footer any more and is because you have nested a bootstrap .row without it being inside a .container element. The .row has negative margins of 15px on either side which are causing the scrollbar. You should have a .container wrapper which has 15px of left and right padding in order to soak up the negative margins of .row without causing a scrollbar. Use the proper structure and the scrollbar will go away.

Comment: I should also point out that the issue was never the footer anyway because the footer and .footer are different elements and the padding was on an inner element so won't affect the width of the footer.

Answer (score 3):

### See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/hbdbqrta/)

Remove `padding-left:5%` from

```
.footer {
    padding-left:5% 
}
```

When you add 15% for left padding, the remaining width available is only 85%.But you are setting width as 100% which causes an Horizontal scroll to your page..

So, if you want that 15% padding set your width as 85% only..

Answer (score 0):

I added:

```
display: inline;
```

to .footer, and it fixed the problem, although you will need to change the padding.

Answer (score 0):

Add a width of 100% to the class footer: .footer. This will resolve your issue.

```
 .footer {
    padding-left: 5%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    }
```